# Parsing Amazon S3 URIs using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, amazon-s3

I need to write a script to scan a Amazon's S3 bucket, looking for newer versions of a software we are testing.
I'm also using `s3cmd` do return the `ls` of that bucket, and the output looks like:

```
                   DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.4.1.2/
                   DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.10a/
                   DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.11a/
                   DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.12a/
                   DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.13a/
```

there's some whitespace in front of DIR. I was using `string.strip().split()` to break that string into tokens, and it looks like:

```
[' ', 'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.4.1.2/', 
'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.10a/', 
'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.11a/', 
'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.12a/', 
'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.13a/',
'2014-02-12 00:33  s3://foo/versions/\n']
```

What I wanted was to use the module `re` and parse that string using a regular expression, but I'm not sure how to produce the appropriate regex that would yield me only the version.
What I needed at the end was an array of the versions like `[4.4.1.2, 4.5.0.10a]`. Let's say the regex for the version is `{d}* which would be`{d}.{d}.{d}.{d}`or`{d}`, or`{d}.{d}.{[A-Z][a-z]}`, which all possible combinations, but letters always after numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your versions are always come after the `versions/` then you can use this example:

```
input = '''
DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.4.1.2/
DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.10a/
DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.11a/
DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.12a/
DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.13a/
'''
print re.findall("versions/([^/]*)/", input)
```

Comment: You beatme with `re.findall`.

Comment: Sabuj, that's awesome, expect for one thing: `>>> a = 'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.4/'
>>> print re.findall("versions/([^/]*)/", output)` returns `[]`

Comment: :-p where did that variable `output` came from??

Comment: @SabujHassan my bad :-p

Comment: @SabujHassan I have one more ... same format, and I have to find the installer this time: it ends with `.run` like in `s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.13a/*installer_name.run`

Comment: If you want to have both version and installer-name then `re.findall("versions/([^/]*)/(\S+)\.run", input)`. if only name then `re.findall("versions/[^/]*/(\S+)\.run", input)`. if you don't want to have the `*` from name then `re.findall("versions/[^/]*/\*(\S+)\.run", input)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re

>>> string = "  DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.4.1.2/"
>>> version_pattern = re.compile(r'.*/versions/(.*)/')
>>> result = version_pattern.search(string)
>>> result.groups()[0]
>>> 4.4.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
pattern = r"DIR\s*s3://foo/versions/(?P<version>(\d\.){3}\d*[a-zA-Z]?)/"
versions = []
for match in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    versions.append(match.groups("version"))
```

Instead of using regex, you can use the following one-liner:

```
# s = your data
[line.split("/")[-2] for line in s.splitlines()]
```

Explanation:

```
>>> s.splitlines()
['DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.4.1.2/',
 'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.10a/',
 'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.11a/',
 'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.12a/',
 'DIR   s3://foo/versions/4.5.0.13a/']

>>> _[0].split("/")
['DIR   s3:', '', 'foo', 'versions', '4.4.1.2', '']

>>> _[-2]
'4.4.1.2'
```